# Regression analysis with All text data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-image

I want to know what is the best approach to handle a regression analysis on all text data type. I have the following data set.

my feature columns are:  Strength, area of development, leadership, satisfactory
values of these columns are predefined set of texts eg. "Continuous Improvement,Self-Development,Coaching and Mentoring,Creativity,Adaptability"

based on the value in these columns I want to predict the label (overall Performance) - Outstanding or Exceeding Expectation  or Meeting Expectation.

what should be the best approach to deal with this dataset ?

Comment: please tell me this is a toy problem

Comment: Indeed it is a toy problem